.NET Core Appsettings get wrong values
I have appsettings storing different blob storage config. However, API occasionally will retrieve wrong blob storage config although it set to read the correct config.
Here's my code - Startup.cs:
services.Configure<AzureConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureConfig"));
services.Configure<AzurePrivateConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("AzurePrivateConfig"));

AppSettings.json:
"AzureConfig": {
   "StorageConnection": "Blob Storage 1 xxxx"
},
"AzurePrivateConfig": {
   "PrivateStorageConnection": "Blob Storage 2 xxxx"
},

AzureConfig.cs:
public class AzureConfig
{
     public string StorageConnection { get; set; }
}

AzurePrivateConfig.cs
public class AzurePrivateConfig
{
     public string PrivateStorageConnection { get; set; }
}

TicketsController.cs:
public class TicketsController : ControllerBase
{
    private IOptions<AzureConfig> azureConfig;

    public TicketsController(IOptions<AzureConfig> azureConfig)
    {
        this.azureConfig = azureConfig;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload([FromForm] UploadAttachmentModel model)
    {
        var storageConnection = azureConfig.Value.StorageConnection;

        // Perform action........
    }
}

Based on the above API, by right system should get the StorageConnection value. However, I found out that sometimes it will grab PrivateStorageConnection value instead. I have no clue why it happened. Help is appreciated.

what happens if you flipped the order of the register in the startup.cs?

Tried. Occasionally it will still read the wrong value.

Does this occur locally or only when deployed?

Also, could you share AzurePrivateConfig class as well?

Added in AzurePrivateConfig class. It happens on both but occassionally.

Hi @CheeMun, Pls check that no configuration sections or environment variables share the same key paths. And no environment-specific appsettings (e.g., appsettings.Development.json) override these configurations incorrectly.
